# Scripting VMware configuration: can I use PowerCLI?

Tags: scripting, vmware

I have an automated task to start, it involves various commands in PowerCLI.
like

```
Allocate Space      New-Datastore Parameter(1)
Browse Datastore        Get-Datastore Parameter(1)      
Remove file     Remove-Item  Parameter(1)   
Cancel task     Stop-Task -Task Parameter(1)
Create virtual machine  New-VM -Name %Parameter(1) -Host Parameter(2) 
Delete virtual machine  Remove-VM %Parameter -DeletePermanently 

Reconfigure virtual machine Set-VM -VM %Parameter(1) -Name Parameter(2)
Assign network      Set-VMGuestNetworkInterface -VMGuestNetworkInterface %  Parameter   (1) -HostUser Admin -HostPassword Pass01 -GuestUser User -GuestPassword Pass02 -Netmask 255.255.255.255 -Gateway 10.23.112.58
and so on...........
...........
```

but the above commands are relevant to configuring VMware in windows environment.

I did a lot of searching in Google but could not find a no-GUI (or command line or scripting) way of performing these actions and I don't think it can be done just using shell commands.

Is there any standard way of doing these things in Unix environments using command line or scripting? Or can I install PowerCLI in Linux and execute the same set of commands?

Do I have to download any tool or there is already some standard tool/command-line that comes
with VMWare to do these type of actions in a Unix environment like [for VirtualBox](http://nakkaya.com/2012/08/30/create-manage-virtualBox-vms-from-the-command-line/)?

Comment: please help this question to be migrated to appropriate site if it doesn't fit here

Answer (score 4):

I have some experience in usage of python library for configuring vmware, [pysphere](http://code.google.com/p/pysphere/).

Possible tasks, (taken from official web site)

- Connect to VMWare's ESX, ESXi, Virtual Center, Virtual Server hosts
- Query hosts, datacenters, resource pools, virtual machines
- VM: Power on, power off, reset, revert to snapshot, get properties, update vmware tools, clone, migrate.
- vSphere 5.0 Guest Operations: create/delete/move files and directories.  - Upload/download files from the guest system.List/start/stop processes in the guest system.
- Create and delete snapshots
- Hosts statistics and performance monitoring

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the VMware SDK for Perl which is bundled with vSphere Command-Line Interface (vCLI), which is the unix pendant for PowerCLI.

You can download it from http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/index.html